# Flutter dynamic image choose and load not working. Exception Asset not found

Tags: flutter, image, android-assets

I'm trying to let the user choose an image, copy it to the internal app folder, and then display it back. I'm getting an error

```
Unable to load asset: /data/user/0/com.my.app/app_flutter/IMG-20230923-WA0001.png 
Exception: Asset not found
```

```
void _getImage() async {
    // Pick an image from the user gallery
    ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
    final imageFile = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (imageFile != null) {
      // Get the application directory
      final String appDirPath = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;

      setState(() {
      int fileNameIndex = imageFile.path.lastIndexOf("/");
      cardBackgroundPath = 
          "$appDirPath${imageFile.path.substring(fileNameIndex)}";
      });

      File imageFileTemp = File(imageFile.path);
      try {
        // Copy the source file to the destination
        await imageFileTemp.copy(cardBackgroundPath);

        // Check if the file was successfully copied
        if (File(cardBackgroundPath).existsSync()) {
          debugPrint('File copied to: $cardBackgroundPath');
        } else {
          debugPrint('Failed to copy the file.');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        // Handle any errors that may occur during the copy operation
        debugPrint('Error copying the file: $e');
      }

      // imageFile.saveTo(cardBackgroundPath);
      debugPrint("CardbackgroundPath: $cardBackgroundPath");
    }
```

- I have verified that the file exists in the right path.
- I also get the below debugPrint output: `I/flutter (17123): File copied to: /data/user/0/com.example.ritual/app_flutter/IMG-20230923-WA0001.jpg`
- Static loading of images are working fine, that is images put into the asset folder and loaded while coding the application, and adding those filepaths into the `pubspec.yaml` file
- I am using Image.asset(, fit:BoxFot.cover, <width & height>), attributes to display the image

Assets in `pubspec.yaml`

```
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/fonts/
    - assets/images/
```

Comment: Make sure you have added the assets image path to pubspec.yaml file

Comment: I have updated my question above, I have those entires in my assets.